# Errors while mounting NFS share from Linux to QNAP NAS

Tags: mount, nfs, qnap

I'm trying to mount a share from a Linux computer to QNAP via NFS.
NOT QNAP NFS share to Linux!
Generally, the share mounts, but after the 3rd attempt:

```
mount -w -vt nfs -o rw,soft -O user=root,password=pass 192.168.0.2:/something_tam /share/CACHEDEV2_DATA/mnt

Result:
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Dec 2 12:31:42 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'soft,vers=4.2,addr=192.168.0.2,clientaddr=192.168.0.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'soft,vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.0.2,clientaddr=192.168.0.7'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'soft,vers=4,addr=192.168.0.2,clientaddr=192.168.0.7'
```

The problem is probebly with the syntax implemented by QNAP.
I tried mount.nfs4, types=4 and others. Errors always pop up.
Maybe someone knows what the syntax of the mount command should look like in the case of QNAP?